# Creating a new probabilistic matrix from two existing ones according to prespecified rules in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, probability, multiplication

I have a problem in my MATLAB code. Let me first give you some explanation about the issue. I have two matrices which represent probabilities of specific outcomes of events. The first one is called DemandProbabilityMatrix or in short DemandP. Entry (i,j) shows the probability that item i is demanded j many times. Similarly, we have a ReturnProbabilityMatrix, i.e. ReturnP. An element of type (i,j) stores the probability that item i is returned j many times.
We want to compute the net demand probability out of these two matrices. For an example:

> DemandP=[ .4 .5 .1]
>   ReturnP=[ .2 .3 .5]

In this case we have 1 item and it can be demanded or returned either 1,2 or 3 times with the given probabilities. To be more specific That item will be demanded just for once with probability .4 .

Then we need to compute the net demand. In this case, net demand can be -2,-1,0,1 or 2. For instance in order to get a net demand of -1 we can either have a demand of 1 and return of 2 or demand of 2 and return of 3. Thus we have

> NetDemandP(1,2)= DemandP(1,1)*ReturnP(1,2)+DemandP(1,2)*ReturnP(1,3).

Thus the NetDemandP should look as:

> NetDemandP=[.20 .37 .28 .13 .02]

I can do this with nested `for` loops but I'm trying to come up with a faster way. In case it helps I have the following `for` loops solutions where `I` denotes the number of rows in `ReturnP` and `DemandP`, `J+1` denotes the number of columns in those matrices.

```
NetDemandP=zeros(I,2*J+1);
    for i=1:I
        for j=1:J+1
            for k=1:J+1
                NetDemandP(i,j-k+J+1)=NetDemandP(i,j-k+J+1)+DemandP(i,j)*ReturnP(i,k);
            end
        end
    end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the *convolution* of your probability density functions. Or, more specifically, you want the convolution of the demand density with the *reverse* of the return density. This is easily achieved in Matlab. For example:

```
DemandP = [.4 .5 .1];
ReturnP = [.2 .3 .5];
NetDemandP = conv(DemandP,fliplr(ReturnP))
```

If you have matrices instead of vectors, then just iterate through the rows:

```
for i = 1:size(DemandP,1)
    NetDemandP(i,:) = conv(DemandP(i,:),fliplr(ReturnP(i,:)))
end
```

Comment: I think this is a perfect answer! Works quite fast and also very neatly written! Thanks Chris, appreciate it.